# Is it Ok pass a ViewModel to screens via Navigation - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I need to implement an app-wide mutable list that holds navigation destinations and pass this around to numerous screens. This seems to work but... is it ok to do it this way?

'''

@Composable
fun AppNavigation (nextScreenViewModel: NextScreenViewModel){

```
val navController = rememberNavController()


        NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = AppViews.HomeView.name) {
   

    composable(route =  AppViews.HomeView.name) {
       
        HomeView(navController = navController,)   
    }
    
    composable(route = AppViews.LearnView.name){
        LearnView(navController = navController,nextScreenViewModel = nextScreenViewModel)
    }

    composable(route = AppViews.PracticeView.name){
        PracticeView(navController = navController,nextScreenViewModel = nextScreenViewModel)
    }
```

'''

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for what do you need a list of destinations? If you wanna just navigate to them you can pass a lambda that navigates to your destination

Comment: The App is an educational App -   a list of screens is generated, each screen provides info/ask questions in  a  particular format.

Comment: it will kill previews so probably not